# Passwordless (key based) SSH Access to a Linux system from a MAC?

Tags: ssh, root, key-authentication, macos

New Edits:

So I went back and did some significant testing and revised my opinions about my problem a little.

First, here's a link to a thorough and quickly graspable diagram of the SSH Handshake (to get on the same page): [SSH Keys Explained](https://serverfault.com/questions/935666/ssh-authentication-sequence-and-key-files-explain).

So I cleaned out the .ssh folders for the user and the root on each of the two Centos7 machine's I'm using - the controller is a VM and the server is metal.

Here are the SSHD_Config values of interest:

```
#Port22, Protocol 2, PermitRootLogin yes, #StrictModes yes, 
PubKeyAuthentication yes, AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys,
AllowUsers root me_meaning_me, PasswordAuthentication yes (only to allow ssh-copy-id operations to start), #PasswordAuthentication no, 
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes, ChallengeResponseAuthentication no,
ClientAliveTime 120, ClientAliveCountMax 720 for tripleo openstack timeout
UsePAM yes, GSSAPI yes
```

Begin: no files or folders in any ~/.ssh/ locations, me-user, root-user, local or server.

1. `ssh me@server` - password accepted - final state: new server fingerprint in new local known_hosts.
2. `ssh-keygen me@server` - no visible result - final state; id_rsa private, id_rsa.pub files in local `~/ssh/`.
3. `ssh-copy-id me@server` - no visible result - final state: `rsa-shaw` in server me's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file named with `me@server`.
4. `me@server` can SSH into server but must provide the server-side password.
5. `ssh-keygen -f root-key root@server` - no visible result - final state: root-key rsa private key and root-key.pub public key in local me's `~/.ssh/`.
6. `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/root-key.pub root@server` - some response about the key and root@server must provide the server-side password.
7. edit server-side `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` - change to `#PasswordAuthentication yes` and `PasswordAuthentication no`.
8. `ssh me@server` succeeds and no password is requested.
9. `ssh root@server` fails with PublicKey, GSSAPI error.
10. Tried many variations of values in `sshd_config` - but revert them all.
11. Used the k-v-m switch to log into server and inspected root's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file - the single key in the file is identical to the key generated for me@server.
12. The `ssh-keygen -f root-key root@sever` produced an identical key and added the `me@server` identity.
13. The `ssh-copy-id -i root-key.pub root@server` moved the key identical to me@server's key to the root's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Now, my original name for this issue was based on having gone through those steps several times over some hours, always with the same results.

So now what do we think?

Comment: "the procedures fail when i try to copy a self-generated id_rsa.pub file..." Please [edit] your question to show exactly what command(s) you are running and exactly what happens, including any error messages. You don't need to be root on the mac to ssh into a remote host as root.

Comment: There is no relation between a user on one machine and another, except that ssh fills in the user name in userName@machineName, if one is not specified, using the current user-name.

Comment: @kenster: thanks for noticing that I left out some details and left over some others - detailing now.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: I appreciate your point-- that there's no 'necessary' relationship between two users on one (or two) control (source) machines who want to SSH into a server(target) machine. However my edits may prove that there can be some unexpected relationships created by the normal SSH command process.

Comment: Testing on macOS 10.14.5 and on Debian 9, your stated command at step 5) produces a "too many arguments" error and an usage listing from `ssh-keygen`, and no new keys generated.

Comment: Thanks for trying it from a MAC. In my Centos7 VM it produces no error and puts a private and public key in the user's ~/.ssh/ folder with the names root-key and root-key.pub, as the ssh-keygen -f examples expect.

Answer (score 4):

If I have read your question correctly you seem to be stuck on the fact your mac does not have matching usernames (including root) with your server.

You really don't need to use a matching username on the client when logging into or setting up access to a server.  If you don't specify a username then the ssh client will assume your current username, but you can *always* specify a different username if you want to using the form: `user@remote_host`

You mentioned that you are using the `ssh-copy-id` command.  On the command line you get get a user manual page for this by typing `man ssh-copy-id`.  For reference it should show you this: https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-copy-id

> ## Synopsis
>
> ```
> ssh-copy-id [-i [identity_file]] [user@]machine
> ```

That is from your *regular* user on the mac you can call:

```
ssh-copy-id root@remote-server
```

Or you can specify which public key to install. eg:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub root@remote-host
```

Comment: @PhillipCouling: I appreciate your patient willingness to address the technicalities. I've updated my question to reflect the verification of the actual behavior of the SSH commands you pointed out.